# Regex: This or that or none

Tags: regex

How would I write a regex to say, "this or that or none of the above?"

Basically, I have the strings `myapplication`, `myapplication.exe`, and `myapplication.app`. How would I write a regex that matches all of these?

For just the first two, I'd use `myapplication(.exe)?`. I *could* use `myapplication(.exe)?(.app)?`, but that would also match `myapplication.exe.app` which should not be matched.

Thoguhts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've almost got it.

```
^myapplication(\.exe|\.app)?$
```

- Use [alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) for "or."
- Note that you need to escape the `.` because [an unescaped period matches any single character.](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)
- [Add anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to ensure the pattern matches the *entire* input.

http://regexr.com/3a50k

Comment: myapplication.exe matches and myapplication.exe.app matches, too. There's nothing in the pattern to stop it from matching both.

Comment: @codekaizen ah, I suppose. Anchor the end points and that's solved. It similarly matches `myapplicationfoobarspameggs` :)

Comment: But now it will only match if it is all one line, which isn't clear.

Comment: Thanks! Never knew alternation existed before now :) I'd accept your answer... but alas, I must wait 10 minutes. Suspense :D haha

Comment: @codekaizen the OP hasn't made clear exactly how the input is passed. This is the hazard with answering regex questions...

Comment: @bobbybee are you trying to match a complete string/line? or extract something from a larger body of text?

Answer (score 1):

To match `.exe` or `.app` or nothing ... match `.exe` or `.app` or nothing:

```
^myapplication\(\.exe\|\.app\|)$
```

or, depending on the flavor of regular expression you're using:

```
^myapplication(\.exe|\.app|)$
```

Note the presence of *nothing* (also known as the empty string) between the `|` and the `)`.

Comment: Why would this approach ever be preferable to simply making the group optional (as in my answer above)? I'm not saying that this approach is invalid _per se_ but it does seem unusual/sub-ideal to me.

Comment: @MattBall: I'm not saying it's necessarily *preferable* (and yours is perfectly valid). But I don't find it unusual. For one thing, it more closely matches the problem statement ("this or that or none of the above").